# Android - onKey events don't fire

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a problem where it seems I can't get key events to fire at all in the emulator (it was working before, but, somehow.. something broke).

Here is some sample code that should fill the second text box with the text of the first when a key is pressed in the first (or if the button is clicked).  But it doesn't do that.

Am I doing something wrong?

Activity class:

```
package abc.def;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Fill extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 EditText e1;
 EditText e2;
 Button b;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        e1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    e2.setText(e1.getText());
    return false;
   }

        });

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    e2.setText(e1.getText());
   }
        });
    }
}
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
<EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/EditText02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
<Button android:text="Click" android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try this by any chance? e2.setText(e1.getText().toString());  I thought .getText() only returns the textview, I could be wrong though...

Comment: I thought `ToString()` was automatically called on any `Object` that needs to be considered as `String`

Comment: Actually, toString() would never be called in this case - getText() returns an object which implements Editable (which extends CharSequence).  setText() takes a CharSequence parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use e1.getText().toString() to get result.

LogCat will be useful to find out the values that are passed around. You can add the following LogCat for finding out similar issues

Log.d("SOMENAME",e1.getText().toString);

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't totally clear.  The code in the event handlers works (if I click on the button, the text box gets filled in as intended).  HOWEVER, the OnKey event never gets fired when typing in the first text box.. and this is the problem.  I don't understand why.

Comment: Well.. I checked the code. Your code is working fine in my emulator. I am using AVD with Android L8.

Comment: Just an update: This code also doesn't function as intended on a physical device using a soft (onscreen) keyboard.  I found a workaround by implementing TextWatcher and using addTextChangedListener() instead, which functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by implementing TextWatcher and using addTextChangedListener() instead.  No clue why this works when the onKeyListener does not - I suspect the keyboard events aren't even reaching my widget for some reason..